# Can I use two NVIDIA gpu cards in a system without SLI support for CUDA computation?

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia, multi-gpu, multiple-gpu

My current system for CUDA applications has one old NVIDIA card, 8800 GTX. I am thinking of adding one more card to it without updating the motherboard. Is it true that as long as I have two PCI-E slots, the two will work? Or I have to purchase a new motherboard enabled SLI support?

Answer (score 3):

Of course you can. Moreover, even if one use multiple GPUs on SLI configuration - for CUDA they will be shown as multiple devices. 
For example, I have a computer with 4 nVidia GPUs on AMD-chip motherboard w/o any SLI support.